ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xkit' when removing nvidia-470
Recently tried to update-upgrade my system and found that nvidia-470 is not working anymore.
Tried to run:
sudo apt-get install -f  

And I'm getting something about xkit not being found:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up nvidia-dkms-470 (470.256.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/quirks-handler", line 26, in <module>
    import Quirks.quirkapplier
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Quirks/quirkapplier.py", line 26, in <module>
    import xkit.xutils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xkit'
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-470 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-470 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-122-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-470
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I get the same error while trying to remove nvidia altougether
Checked xutils and seems to be there
pip install xutils                            130 ↵  
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: xutils in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.2.2)

All comands: autoremove, purge nvidia and upgrade give the same error about the missing module.
